# Adding string element to an Array Java

Tags: java, loops, jtextarea

I am trying to get a string element to print to 1 spot in an array but every time it execute it takes up all (5) spaces. Ultimately I am trying to get a JButton to assign the string value to the strArray[a] space and appear on a JTextArea

Code:

```
    class Listener1 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

            for(int a = 0; a<strArray.length; a++){
                strArray[a] = "";
                if(e.getSource() == coke){
                    total += 1.5;
                    strArray[a] = "Coke";
                    System.out.println(strArray[a]);


                    orderArea.setText(strArray1);

                } else if(e.getSource() ==milk){
                    total += 1.00;
                    String milk1 = "Milk - $1.00";
                    System.out.println(milk1);
                    strArray[a] = milk1;
                    orderArea.setText(strArray1);

                }
            }

        }
```

Here is the result that is printed:

Coke
Coke
Coke
Coke
Coke
Milk - $1.00
Milk - $1.00
Milk - $1.00
Milk - $1.00
Milk - $1.00

Here is the result I want:

Coke
Milk - $1.00

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific about what the array should contain after your listener has fired and what it actually contains instead. Can you provide printouts of the array contents as it should look and what it does look like?

Comment: What is printed out:Coke
Coke
Coke
Coke
Coke
Milk - $1.00
Milk - $1.00
Milk - $1.00
Milk - $1.00
Milk - $1.00

What it should look like:
Coke
Milk - $1.00

Comment: Add it to your question using the "edit" button. You should also tell us what the expected result is.

Comment: thanks for the patience, still getting used to Stack Overflow, your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to exit the loop once one of the two if conditions are met. Just use `break;`

```
class Listener1 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

            for(int a = 0; a<strArray.length; a++){
                strArray[a] = "";
                if(e.getSource() == coke){
                    total += 1.5;
                    strArray[a] = "Coke";
                    System.out.println(strArray[a]);
                    orderArea.setText(strArray1);
                    break;

                } else if(e.getSource() ==milk){
                    total += 1.00;
                    String milk1 = "Milk - $1.00";
                    System.out.println(milk1);
                    strArray[a] = milk1;
                    orderArea.setText(strArray1);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: my next question is now that i can assign individual elements, how do I get all the elements printed onto a JTextArea, when I click the button the item appears in the JTextArea but is replaced once I click another button